# 100 viewport height not working in Safari iOS 15 New

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, viewport

I’m having issues with Safari iOS 15 bottom tab. My previous question a user said it had already been answered [here][1]. But this doesn't solve my issue, that question was from 7 years ago and this seems like a iOS 15 specific issue.

I've tried env(safe-area-inset-bottom) but that isn't working.

The 100vh is ignoring the Safari tab bar.

I need the heading to be vertically centered, so I have a grid with 3 rows:

Top row: `8em` for Logo
Middle row: `1fr` for Heading
Bottom row: `8em` to leave room for position fixed menu elements.

It all looks great on other mobile devices with no bottom tab bar and in Safari desktop preview of iPhone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYVgy.jpg

But on the actual iPhone running iOS 15, there’s no centering happening.

This is what happens when the page loads:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/chkKJ.png

If I hide the toolbar it looks good.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5fhh.png

I want the grid to be responsive to the Safari tab bar.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.